# Text on one side and figure on the other side of A3 paper

Tags: floats, positioning, minipage

For now, I have two minipages in a minipage on a A3 page, and the text should be on the left in normal height and the figure to the right (which works).
I have a problem with the text in a minipage being placed too low on the page. 
my code for the page is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\begin{document}


\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=16.5in \pdfpageheight=11.7in
%\chapter{Synthesis overview}
\label{Overview}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][8in][t]{14in}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{7in}
\chapter{Experimental Overview}
normal text
The thesis was devided into five experimental phases:
\begin{description}
  \item[I] .....
  \item[II] Full membrane immobilization and testing. 
\end{description}

\end{minipage}% 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{7in}
\includegraphics[width=7in]{Figures/SynthesisOverview}
\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}%
\clearpage 
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage
\eject \pdfpagewidth=8.3in \pdfpageheight=11.7in
```

And this is the output i get:
[image: The output right now]

It does not make a difference if i dont use \chaptor for the text.
And if i remove [t][8in] from the first minipage all the figure and text skips to the next page, and still doesn't show the full text (as in the picture)

Comment: `\raggedbottom` should shift the text on the left to the top, but it will persist to the rest of the document, which you may not want.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you for answering, but it did not help to add \raggedbottom. i think something is wrong with my minipage environments perhaps but i cannot identify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{7in}
\includegraphics[width=7in]{Figures/SynthesisOverview}
\end{minipage}%
```

The minipage here isn't doing anything very useful as `\includegraphics` is already a box, and `minipage` just wraps it in another box.

the problem is that `[t]` means make the reference point of the minipage the baseline of the top row, but here there is only one row, with the image, and its reference point is on its bottom edge.

So as you show the top of the left box aligns with the bottom of the image.

so just use

```
\raisebox{-.9\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=7in]{Figures/SynthesisOverview}%
 }
```

or `adjustbox` package and

```
  \includegraphics[width=7in,vertical-align=T]{Figures/SynthesisOverview}%
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i used the first option and it worked perfectly :)